# Access Right dependency

Tags: algorithm

[image]

The question I have to solve is at t = 70 b revokes access rights from c. Now I'm confused, because the only way we are getting t = 70 is if we go from a to c, do we remove rights from a to c, if so which of the paths from c will we remove and will d remain the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and [mre] then edit your post.